# Converting dates in in MacOS Bash

Tags: bash, macos, date, terminal, zsh

First post! Learning bash and I have a list of dates from combined sources that I don't have control over that look like this:

```
1 July 2023
3 July 2023
10 July 2023
August 1, 2023
August 8, 2023
July 1, 2023
July 3, 2023
July 9, 2023
July 10, 2023
```

What I'm trying to do is convert them to 2023-07-01.

What I'm doing now is chopping up the variable and reordering things:

```
#   Grab Date From Filename
event_date_year=$(cut -d ' ' -f 6 <<<"$event_filename")
event_date_month=$(cut -d ' ' -f 4 <<<"$event_filename")
event_date_day="0"$(cut -d ' ' -f 5 <<<"$event_filename")
#   Trim unneeded zero
event_date_day=${event_date_day:-2}
event_date=$event_date_year"-"$event_date_month"-"$event_date_day
```

My next step is to loop through a list of months and replace them with numbers.

And I have to detect the "other" date format and fix those.

It occurs to me there's *got* be be a better way to do this, but I'm at a bit of a loss. I tried a few things with date, but it doesn't seem to detect the incoming date format.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash` and `zsh`?

Comment: `${event_date_day:-2}` should be `${event_date_day: -2}`. You need a space so it's not confused with the syntax for specifying a default value for the variable.

Comment: Have you considered using the `date` command to parse the dates and convert to another format?

Comment: Can you install `gdate` from coreutils, e.g. with [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils)?  That version of date can parse multiple formats, so the command would just be `event_date=$(gdate -d $inputdate -I`).

Comment: For the mapping of month names to month numbers, I would use an associative array. You did not specify, how the "list of dates" is provided (for instance, in an array, or in a file). If it is a file, I would transform it into the "canonical form" you are looking for, using awk (or something similar). This means that you have a single process which processes all dates.

Comment: If you install the GNU coreutils (using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), for instance), you will have access to a more powerful date utility and `date -d "my date" +'%Y-%m-%d'` will work with all date formats you show.

Comment: I know this is tagged `bash`/`zsh`, but I would use `dateutil.parser` or `dateparser` from Python. Using macOS's BSD `date` may not the best way if trying to parse dates in differing formats from different sources.

Comment: Note that the Bash that is included with macOS is **very old**. If you absolutely have to use Bash (rather than Zsh or a sane shell like Elvish) you should install it using Homebrew to get an up to date version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `date` command](https://ss64.com/osx/date.html) to parse and format the date.

Use a `case` statement to match the two different formats, `<day> <month> <year>` and `<month> <day>, <year>`.

```
event_filename='1 July 2023'
case "$event_filename" in
    [1-9]*) event_date=$(date -j -f '%d %B %Y' +'%Y-%m-%d' "$event_filename") ;;
    [A-Z]*) event_date=$(date -j -f '%B %d, %Y' +'%Y-%m-%d' "$event_filename") ;;
    *) echo "Unrecognized date format";
       exit 1
esac
echo "$event_date"
```

Comment: I think this would fail for  date `August 1, 2023`, which the OP gave an example.  You need to querey the first character of `event_filename` and set the date format accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a case statement.

Comment: Wow, thanks Barmar! That's exactly what I needed. Clearly I wasn't getting the date function right when I was messing around with it. And now I can read up on case/esac to understand it better.